# How to reject new tasks in newSingleThreadExecutor when another task is running

Tags: multithreading, java-8, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, java-threads

The actual scenario is Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor instance is executing a long-running task, I need to reject the new requests for this task until the completion of an existing one. while rejecting new requests, I need to simply send a message called "Thread is already running a task! Please wait until it completes".

Is it possible to implement using the newSingleThreadExecutor? Can Anyone Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

The factory `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` returns the equivalent to `new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>())`, except that it is wrapped in another `ExecutorService` to prevent other code from casting it to `ThreadPoolExecutor` and changing the configuration. The wrapper also adds finalization support which you should not rely on anyway.

So you can construct a similar executor and alter its setup to your needs.

```java
ExecutorService es = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    new SynchronousQueue<>());
```

A `SynchronousQueue` has no capacity but can only hand elements over to already waiting consumers, i.e. will accept a `Runnable` only when there is already an idle worker thread. When the queue rejects the new job, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` will check its configured thread count and either, start a worker thread (at most one here) or call into a `RejectedExecutionHandler`. The default handler does throw a `RejectedExecutionException`, so we’re basically done with your requirements here.

The finetuning we can do, is to change the message of the `RejectedExecutionException` by providing our own `RejectedExecutionHandler`:

```java
ExecutorService es = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    new SynchronousQueue<>(),
    (runnable, executor) -> { throw new RejectedExecutionException(
        "Thread is already running a task! Please wait until it completes");
    });
```

When the amount of code having access to the `ExecutorService` is rather small and you can trust it to not doing things like casting `es` back to `ThreadPoolExecutor` and mess around, you can keep it this way. Otherwise, you can protect it against such modifications by wrapping it:

```java
ExecutorService es = Executors.unconfigurableExecutorService(
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 200L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>(),
    (runnable, executor) -> { throw new RejectedExecutionException(
        "Thread is already running a task! Please wait until it completes");
    }));
```

Now we are as close as we can get to the behavior of `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` plus your deviations, without implementing our own executor. The only thing this executor doesn’t have, is finalization support, but as [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145304) suggests, it’s not a good idea to have it anyway. Take care to invoke `shutdown()` on it at the end of its lifetime (unless it overlaps with a call to `System.exit(…)` anyway).

The behavior can be tested with a program like

```java
Future<?> previous = null;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int jobID = i;
    System.out.println(jobID + " Trying to submit job");
    try {
        Future<?> next = es.submit(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(200);
            System.out.println("job " + jobID);
            return null;
        });
        if(previous != null && !previous.isDone()) {
            throw new AssertionError("new job accepted before previous completed");
        }
        previous = next;
    } catch(RejectedExecutionException ex) {
        System.out.println("rejected: " + ex);
    }
    Thread.sleep(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(90, 190));
}
```

This program attempts to submit multiple jobs and will throw an `AssertionError` if a job is accepted while the previous is not completed.